# Pagination in Flask using MySql

Tags: python, mysql, pagination, flask

I searched a lot about it. All the articles i get include SQLAlchemy and none of them deal with mysql. I am working with flask and i have a database in mysql and i need to display the data in pages. Like 1000 images, per page 10 so 100 pages.
In mysql we can do pagination with the help of limit. And the routes can be:

```
@app.route('/images', defaults={'page':1})
@app.route('/images/page/<int:page>')
```

I need to ask is this all that is needed for pagination? or am i forgetting something important here?
and mysql syntax would be:

```
db = mysql.connect('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'img')
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT Id,Title,Img FROM image ORDER BY RAND() limit 20 offset 0;')
data = list(cursor.fetchall())
```

to get the first 20 results but how to get the next according to the pageno.?
Flask-paginate library works only for tSQLAlchemy.

Comment: Have you checked out http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/44/

Comment: I did. It wasn't able to understand it. That's why i asked for help

Comment: What's the reason you don't want to use SqlAlchemy, or another ORM? Dealing with pure SQL is unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: No mysql is faster and besides my whole program is running on it and i have all the database made up there

Comment: Now can anyone help me figure it out?

Comment: "mysql is faster" - faster than what? I suspect you don't really understand the difference between MySQL(a database) and SqlAlchemy (an object-relational mapper that talks to the database).

Comment: @DanielRoseman i didn't mean to offend you and yeah i don't understand sqlalchemy yet and so for the mean time i'm avoiding it.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
@app.route('/images', defaults={'page':1})
@app.route('/images/page/<int:page>')
def abc(page):
    perpage=20
    startat=page*perpage
    db = mysql.connect('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'img')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT Id,Title,Img FROM image limit %s, %s;', (startat,perpage))
    data = list(cursor.fetchall())
```

May be this will help.

Comment: Thanks but is there no need to use any library or something?

Comment: Actualy, the limit clause would be `limit ?, ?` and then you would pass a tuple as the second argument to `cursor.execute` (e. g. `cursor.execute("your sql here with params ?, ?", (start_at, per_page))`)

Comment: @AarushiIgn - you don't want to use `%` (`string.format`) - instead, pass the params as the second argument to `execute`.  Otherwise you may be leaving the application open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: What if we have arguments in our url as get method ? Here you defined two Endpoint but if we need only one ? And in that one we can support args

Answer (score 2):

Try this [flask-mysql-paginate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kGIk.png)

You could then call the {{paginate.links}} in your html file

Answer (score 1):

Here it is, pure SQL solution.

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT [offset,] rows;
or
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT rows OFFSET offset;
```

For example:

```
select * from user
limit 100 offset 850100;
```